# GFI's have no power in both my bathrooms

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have two GFI's that have no power. I have check all outlets and all switches, and they are wired correct.  I just don't know where to go from here. I was hoping to not need an electrician. Everything in my home has power and is working but the two GFI's in both the main and master bathrooms.

Comment: Have you checked circuit breakers?  Are there any other gfci's anywhere else?

Comment: Go on a GFCI hunt.  Check near the breaker panel, any wet or potentially wet area such as kitchen, laundry, basement, garage etc.  You will undoubtedly find another.  Then you will need to check resetting each location until you find the correct order.  What likely happened is that in the past someone added GFCI's to a circuit that already has one. The nuisance now is that you have to reset all of them, instead of one, and you have to know what order to reset them.

Comment: When Tyson says "wet area", he doesn't mean locations with water problems.  He means locations designated in the Code as potentially damp or wet locations, generally wherever water is used or often found...  kitchens, laundry rooms, garages, basements etc.

Comment: When you check circuit breakers, be aware that many are not visually obvious that they have tripped. You may need to turn them off and on again to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, this:  Modern Code says bathroom receptacle circuits must either a) power only loads in that bathroom, or b) power receptacles only in any bathroom.  And those receptacles must be GFCI protected.

My guess is your builder chose option (b), and installed a *GFCI circuit breaker* on that circuit, and put "GFCI protected" stickers on the bathroom receptacles.  Second, the homeowner tore off those stickers because they're ugly.  Third, they sold the house and some idiot real estate agent said "these don't look like GFCI receptacles, upgrade" and they did.

So now you have a GFCI (breaker) feeding a GFCI (outlet) possibly feeding another GFCI (outlet).  This is like an Escher drawing or a "yo dawg" meme.  Any ground fault or test will trip all of them up the chain.  Worse, some cheap GFCIs trip when power is disconnected!  So you must reset them in the correct sequence down the chain.

Go down to your breaker panel and I bet you find a breaker marked "bathroom" that has a "TEST" button on it.  (If there isn't a RESET, it is accomplished by turning the breaker off and on.)

Then, try resetting each of your downstream GFCIs.  Presumably one more will reset that wouldn't reset before.  Then find the next that will reset, etc.

For any GFCI, if *this* GFCI causes *another* GFCI to trip, then replace *this* GFCI with a plain receptacle with a "GFCI protected" sticker.

Use the salvaged GFCI receptacles to protect other circuits.

Comment: In our area, most houses built in the 80's have one GFCI outlet next to the panel that also serves as the required convenience outlet.  That outlet usually feeds the bathroom outlets.  They rarely used GFCI breakers and they used as few "expensive" outlets as possible.  It's very common for those houses to have a whole bunch of daisy chained GFCI outlets.  It's also the panel convenience outlets that no one thinks to check, often not even realizing  it exists.

Comment: @Tyson great point, and that's *exactly* what I do to retrofit GFCIs.  Put the GFCI right next to the panel, and run LOAD to the circuit.